# cURL unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have read and tried thousands of solutions in different posts and none of them seems to work with me. This three are example of that.

[cURL is unable to use client certificate , in local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470225/curl-is-unable-to-use-client-certificate-in-local-server)

[php openssl_get_publickey() and curl - unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708553/php-openssl-get-publickey-and-curl-unable-to-use-client-certificate-no-key)

[Getting (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?) from curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799478/getting-58-unable-to-use-client-certificate-no-key-found-or-wrong-pass-phrase)

I received a `.p12` certificate which I converted to `.pem` file in https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

The password is correct otherwise it wouldn't convert it.

```
$xml = 'my xml here';
$url = 'https://qly.mbway.pt/Merchant/requestFinancialOperationWS';

$headers = array( 
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"', 
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml), 
    'Accept: text/xml', 
    'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
    'Pragma: no-cache'
); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, base_url() . 'public/cert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'my password here');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); 

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

if(!$data)
    print_r('ERROR: ' . curl_error($ch));
else
    print_r('SUCCESS: ' . curl_error($ch));
```

I have tried with SoapUI application and works fine but with cURL I'm receiving the error:

> unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

I have tried without success:

1. Disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and/or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`
2. Add `CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE` and/or `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` fields

**EDIT 1:**

I have been trying around with SOAPClient besides cURL and it seems that the error might be the headers.

My headers after `print_r($soapClient)` are the following:

```
Host: qly.mbway.pt
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""
Content-Length: 1750
```

I would like to know how can I remove the `action=""`? I tried to extend the original class without success in terms of changing the header.

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient 
{   
   public function __construct($wsdl, $options = array())
   {
     $ctx_opts = array('http' => array('header' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/soapyyyyyml')));

     $ctx = stream_context_create($ctx_opts);

     parent::__construct($wsdl, array('stream_context' => $ctx));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** with cURL.

The problem was the path of the `pem` file.

I was using `base_url() . 'public/cert.pem'` but that's not possible. Instead I need to use a relative path such as `./public/cert.pem`.